# c++ notation - namespace - class - function

Tags: c++, notation

I'm following a simple tutorial in order to create a DLL.
In the process, I got a bit confused with some notation in the cpp file

```
dll.h - the header file
#blablablabla
namespace TutTest {
    class TutTestClass { //for very complicated math!!!
    public:
        static dll_API double Add(double a, double b);
        static dll_API double Subtract(double a, double b);
        static dll_API double Multiply(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

---

```
dll.cpp - the cpp file :)
#blablablabla include and such
namespace TutTest{
    double TutTest::Add(double a, double b){
        return a + b;
    }
    double TutTestClass::Subtract(double a, double b){ 
        return a - b;
    }
    double TutTest::TutTestClass::Multiply(double a, double b){
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

On the above .cpp file, the default notation (used in the tutorial) is "double TutTest::...", however I played around with it and noticed that both "TutTestClass::" and "TutTest::TutTestClass::" seem valid, as the IDE doesn't throw out any error/warning.

So I was wondering, do the 3 notations mean the same? are they equivalent? 
if yes, is there any difference between the notations apart from personal coding style?
Or do those notations differ in meaning from each other?

Comment: It shouldn't be compiled because `TutTest::Add(...` is a error

Comment: Is this really related to a notation? Perhaps you meant namespace and scopes? You don't do anything with notations. You use one, pretty standard.

Comment: If you have a `TutTest` namespace, why name the class within `TutTestCClass`?  Seems silly to me.  Just name it `Class` or something else.

Comment: @luk32 you may be right, that just reflects my still superficial knowledge :p

Comment: @JohnDibling yeah, I noticed that when playing around with it a 2nd time. renamed it to TTestClass. if you're asking because of the long class name, it's mostly irrelevant since it's just a test :p, and I wanna use more classes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TutTestClass::Subtract` is the correct one. `Subtract` is a (static) member function of class `TutTestClass`, so you have to qualify it accordingly.

`TutTest::TutTestClass::Multiply` is technically correct, but weird. Inside namespace `TutTest`, the name `TutTestClass` refers to `TutTest::TutTestClass` automatically, so it's superfluous to qualify that name explicitly.

`TutTest::Add` shouldn't compile. What this attempts to do is define a namespace-scope function `Add` in namespace `TutTest`. However, you can only use a qualified name for declaring a namespace-scope function when

1. the function has already been declared in the namespace, AND
2. the declaration happens *outside* the namespace in question.

None of these applies in your case.

Comment: So I could write "class TutTestClass{ double TutTestClass::Add()}", and here "TutTestClass::" is redundant as well?
What about "namespace TutTest{ class TutTestClass{}}", "namespace TutTest" would be redundat here, right?

Comment: @VLV As a rule of thumb, you can only qualify something which already exists. Using `TutTestClass::Add` to declare `Add` *inside* `TutTestClass` is an error, it has to be just `Add`. I don't understand your comment about `namespace TutTest` being redundant: you need to open the namespace to put declarations into it.

Comment: I see, that also makes sense :) the namespace TutTest got open in the header file, so as it has already been used, then it's redundant to use it also on the cpp file, if that made sense

Comment: @VLV It's not redundant because it was opened in the header file; it was closed there again (by the matching `}`). It's redundant in the .cpp file because the declaration is inside it (between the `{` and `}` delimiting the namespace).

Answer (score 1):

A namespace include itself and its anchestores, hence `TutTest::` inside `TutTest` does nothing.

But just because of that, `TutTest::Add` is not the same as `TutTest::TutTestClass::Add`. (you are in fact defining another function, that have never been declared)

inside the `namaspace TutTest { ... }` you can avoid `TutTest::` but to define class members (even if static) outside the class baces, you need to qualify the function name with the class it belongs.